# Why did Shishupala and his supporters thought Krishna would take away Rukmini?

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana

Srimad Bhagavatham says,

The day when Shishupala and Rukmini's wedding was decided, Shishupala and his supporters (Śālva, Jarāsandha, Dantavakra and Vidūrath [SB 10.53.17](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/53/17) ) said if Krishna and Balarama comes here and try to take away Rukmini then they all will fight against them.

> To secure the bride for Śiśupāla, the kings who envied Kṛṣṇa and Balarāma came to the following decision among themselves: **“If Kṛṣṇa comes here with Balarāma and the other Yadus to steal the bride**, we shall band together and fight Him.” Thus those envious kings went to the wedding with their entire armies and a full complement of military conveyances. [SB.10.53.18-19](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/53/18-19)

But, Rukmini sends a trusted brahmana with a message to Krishna in which She express her love for Him and asks Krishna to marry Her. This message was confidential which was between Rukmini and Brahmana only.

> The brāhmaṇa said: This is the confidential message I have brought with me, O Lord of the Yadus. Please consider what must be done in these circumstances, and do it at once. [SB 10.52.44](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/52/44)

My questions is:

If Rukmini's message to Krishna was confidential then how could Shishupala and his supporters even think Krishna would take her away? Was there any link between Krishna and Rukmini earlier which was known to Shishupala or others that made then think so?

Comment: any kshatriya was allowed to take any bride away by force. so they would have been wary of any other king. and Shishupala was naturally at odds with Krishna, so there could have been enough doubt in his mind even without knowing of the letter.

Comment: @ram Any reference?

Comment: reference for kshatriyas being allowed to take away brides? and i'm simply opening up a different line of assumption than the assumption you made that shishupala might have known about the letter.

Comment: @KrishnaShweta because Rukmi know that Krishna is also loving her....